How to display the Rupee symbol (₹) in an ASP.NET MVC application?
<tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FlightDeparture)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FlightDuration)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FlightArrival)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FlightStatus)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        **@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FlightPrice)**
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <a asp-action="AddOrEdit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" asp-route-FlightsId="@item.FlightsId">Edit</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <a asp-action="Details" class="btn btn-outline-info" asp-route-FlightsId="@item.FlightsId">Details</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <a asp-action="Delete" class="btn btn-outline-danger" asp-route-FlightsId="@item.FlightsId" new { onclick="return confirm('Are sure wants to delete this flight?');" })>Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>

How to display the Rupee symbol (₹) in the FlightPrice column of my table in an ASP.NET MVC application?
Like this -> ex: 65000 to -> ₹65000

This can be done in various ways:

If you want to show just a single hard-coded currency symbol, you can append the symbol or its uni-code character like:
₹@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FlightPrice)


Or
&#8377;@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FlightPrice)


If currnecy symbol is being fetched from database, in that case add one more field in your model and pass symbol in that field and either you can append the value here, or you can append currency symbol at server end in FlightPrice like:
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CurrencySymbol)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FlightPrice)


OR
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new YourModel();
    model.FlightPrice = model.CurrencySymbol + model.FlightPrice
    return View(model);
}

OR
you can get Flight Price value with appended currency symbol directly while fetching values from database
